# play playlist (.pls) using Silverlight MediaElement

Tags: c#, silverlight, mediaelement

I'm starting to learn a bit of Silverlight programing to write some stuff for Windows 8, havn't done a lot with it yet or with audio but I am trying to stream a playlist using a `MediaElement`.

I tried:

```
OutputMedia.Source=new Uri("http://provisioning.streamtheworld.com/pls/KISWFM.pls",UriKind.Absolute);
OutputMedia.Play();
```

but I don't hear anything playing so I have to assume it doesn't work :)

Can anyone give me a few pointers please?

Comment: [Read the PLS, extract the file names, play them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8304270/266143).

Comment: I tried that as well... if I change the URI to one of the URL's (http://8283.live.streamtheworld.com:80/KISWFM_SC) I get the same result, nothing happens...

Answer (score 0):

Try https://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/

> Shoutcast MediaStreamSource is a MediaStreamSource
>   implementation of the Shoutcast protocol for Silverlight. This
>   MediaStreamSource allows both Silverlight 4+ OOB and Windows Phone 7
>   applications to consume a Shoutcast stream using a MediaElement.
>
> Currently, Mp3 and AAC+ Shoutcast streams are supported on Windows
>   Phone. However, ONLY Mp3 is supported on Desktop Silverlight.
>
> There is also limited (i.e. somewhat untested) M3u and PLS playlist
>   support.
>
> Please report any issues playing Shoutcast streams with the following:
>   * URI to the problem stream
>   * Description of the problem
>   * The error returned (or not!) from the Shoutcast MediaStreamSource